# ¿Por que no me guarda los datos correctamente el procedimiento almacenado?

Tags: mysql, laravel, stored-procedure, laravel-7

Estoy intentando pasar los dato del procedimiento almacenado, desde el controlador pero no se que me esta generando un error, que solo me crea el registro en la tabla que quiero, pero no me guarda ningún dato en la tabla.

**PA:**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE movimientos_stock (
 IN usuario_fk BIGINT,
 IN producto_fk BIGINT,
 IN area_fk BIGINT,
 IN tipo_area_fk BIGINT,
 IN tipo_movimiento VARCHAR(100),
 IN created_at  DATETIME)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `movimientos`(usuario_fk, producto_fk, area_fk, tipo_area_fk, tipo_movimiento, created_at)
    VALUES (usuario_fk, producto_fk, area_fk, tipo_area_fk, tipo_movimiento, created_at);
END;
```

**CONTROLADOR**

En el controlador lo uso así:

```
DB::unprepared("CALL movimientos_stock($usuario_fk, $producto_fk, $area_fk, $tipo_area_fk, $tipo_movimiento, $created_at)");
```

> Las variables que estoy agregando ya están declaradas y si están recibiendo los datos que necesito.

Y el resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> como se observa me registra, pero no me guarda nada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El tema es que si revisamos [la documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database#running-an-unprepared-statement) puedes notar que el método **`unprepared(....)`** esta pensado para ejecutar queries donde no se hará vinculación entre marcadores y variables (*esto puede ser la causa del fallo*).

Entonces como tu *PA* no esta orientado en devolver un resultado de la operación ejecutada, puedes optar por el método: [**`statement(...........)`**](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database#running-a-general-statement) considerando que el mismo recibe 2 argumentos:

- Un string con la query a ejecutar (necesario)
- Un array con las variables con las cuales hará binding usados en la query (opcional)

  ```
  DB::statement("CALL movimientos_stock(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", [
      $usuario_fk, 
      $producto_fk, 
      $area_fk, 
      $tipo_area_fk, 
      $tipo_movimiento, 
      $created_at,
  ]);
  ```

No olvides importar a DB de esta forma:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @BetaM, funciono con  `DB::statement`.